# android how to use listview instead of scrollview

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, scrollview

in my app's main page, i have 10 lists i've created with recycler view. lists have limited count of items .
and an image slider at top and 2 simple imageview. every recycler view is inside a fragment and i initialize fragments at main activity then add fragments to containers of type framelayout inside nested scroll view. now i've seen in similar apps that views are creating on scroll down and i think that apps are using probably listview  but in my app all views are created at once and im afraid this effects my app first page load time so have bad impact on app performance.
i dont know how can i use list view containing different type of views like mine.
this is my main activity's latout:

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
android:id="@+id/submaincontainer"
>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#f8f8f8"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/searchlay"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/simplebacklessroundtool"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/search"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/search"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/search"
                android:id="@+id/b1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="جستجو در "
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="-20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/b1"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/sinbadred"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarprog"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/navigator"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/slidercontainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="6dp">

            <com.denzcoskun.imageslider.ImageSlider
                android:id="@+id/image_slider"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:iss_auto_cycle="true"
                app:iss_delay="0"
                app:iss_period="2500" />
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/containerhorizsubgroup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/containerdiscount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/containeruserseensubg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/containernews"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/poster0"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/userseencontainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/offercontainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
           />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/containercustomsubgroup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/mostvisitedcontainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            />


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/userseenbygroupcontainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/poster1"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/mostSoldcontainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/recentcontainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#f8f8f8"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/tab_color_selector"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/tab_color_selector"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:menu="@menu/bottomnavmenu" />
```

i load my fragments containing recycler views to those frame layouts
i wonder how can i build this with list view so all views not created at once but by scroll.
any help well appropriated.
i post some of my app main view  at bottom.
thanks

[image: main page]
[image: main page]
[image: main page]

Comment: [Epoxy](https://github.com/airbnb/epoxy) is the answer

Answer (score 1):

Instead of fragments, you can use recycler view with view types
like
ViewHolder for image slider
View Holder for image Views
View Holder for horizontal List
e.g
https://medium.com/better-programming/create-heterogeneous-views-using-recyclerview-in-android-e2ad626686f6